# Looking for a tool(GUI or Form) that serves as front-end to Oracle SQL database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my company we process many ad-hoc data extraction requests for which we write new SQL scripts each time.  I'd like to provide an enterprise-wide front-end for users with no SQL knowledge to create queries using some point-and-click functionality.  The Oracle database would be on the back-end and all SQL code hidden from the user.  Is MS Access the best tool for this?

I'm working on connecting the oracle database to MS Access forms, but I'm not sure if this is extensible enough to be used across an entreprise, possibly hosted over the company intranet.

Going forward, I'd expect to be able to direct users to land on a page with a drop down menu and possibly some cell inputs that perform basic sql queries (based on user selection and input).

Comment: This question is off-topic for this forum ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ) - you could ask your Oracle rep for their solutions (like Application Express), but there are also hundreds of tools that do this kind of thing, so this would be a very long discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Opinion based, certainly, but - nonetheless, I'd suggest **Oracle Application Express** (Apex).

In a few words:

- it is installed within the database
- development is done via any browser
- users will *love* its **Interactive Reports** - it is a report you create for them, but still they have a lot of possibilities of rearranging the layout, such as

  - sorting,
  - adding/hiding columns,
  - filtering,
  - aggregating,
  - displaying charts ...
- they (uses) don't have to install anything - just like you, a developer, they will use their browsers

For more info and - to see how it looks like - go to [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/en/), create a (free) account and run preinstalled application(s). I hope you'll like what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Already there are n number of tools built to give a UI and keeping the source code hidden of built in like ETL tools Informatica, Talend or Reporting tools likr Cognos, Spotfire etc